# VS code C++ code runner setup in remote server

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, remote-debugging

Hello I am trying to setup VS code code runner setup in a remote server so that I can use the VS code debugger. Usually when I run code from the terminal, I have to at first load the g++ module.
My usual c++ compile and run sequence goes as:

```
module load Compilers/gcc-4.9.2
g++ -o test test.cpp
./test
```

Now after installing code runner, if I try to run it in vs code by clicking the run button, I get the following error:

```
[Running] cd "/data/<server_name>/users/<username>/" && g++ practice.cpp -o practice && "/data/<server_name>/users/<username>/"test
/bin/sh: g++: command not found
```

How should I setup my VS code to run cpp files and use the debugger feature in this remote server? I use VS Code remote development successfully in my setup as well.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your *Visual Studio Code UI* below right, you'll find the possibility to call the setting for your workspace:

[image]

You should be able to update your setting to find the installed compiler in your remote system. The JSON setting looks like this:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "gnu11",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

It is also possible to set it using the UI.
For more details, you could also check the [official site](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw).